# Livewire - 100 Components - Parent and Child

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

What is better when it comes to performance (Payloads)

> Approach 1

**index.php**

```
@livewire('child1')

@livewire('child2')

.
.
.
@livewire('child100')
```

> Approach 2

**index.php**

```
@livewire('parent')
```

**parent.blade.php**

```
@livewire('child1')

@livewire('child2')

.
.
.
@livewire('child100')
```

Comment: If your `parent` compoent is doing nothing other than wrapping your `child` components (i.e. not managing state of lifecycles), then don't bother with `parent`.

Comment: Also, if you're using child components in a loop, make sure to key them. ( `@foreach ($parent->children as $child) @livewire('child', $child, key($child->id)) @endforeach` )